# Java Remote: No such file or directory

Tags: java, netbeans, remote-debugging

I am using Netbeans to execute my programs remotely on my Raspberry Pi. But somehow an error occurs, because a needed File is not found, which seems to be copied correctly.

Error-Code: `file:/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/ExampleProject/dist/ExampleProject.jar!/files/GeoLiteCity.dat (No such file or directory)`

When I look into the dist directory and open the ExampleProject.jar file, the file files/GeoLiteCity.dat seems to be there.

[image]

I just don't get why this error occurs.

Comment: Request that the pi sends ExampleProject.jar to your pc.

Comment: Try examining it.

Comment: That is not a file. It's a resource inside a jar file. Don't use file IO to read resources inside jars of the classpath. Use the ClassLoader. File IO is for reading... files, on the file system.

Comment: My pc transfers the data correctly to /home/pi/NetBeansProjects/ExampleProject/dist. In the dist directory on my pc is the same stuff as in the dist directory on the pi.

Comment: the call in my program looks like File file = getFile("/files/GeoLiteCity.dat");

Comment: when I run the program locally, it works perfectly. But not when running remote on pi.